# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to render a table from array of object using react-bootstrap-table. This is the code :

```
render() {
  var products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Product1",
    price: 120
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Product2",
    price: 80
  }];

  return (
    <div>
      <BootstrapTable data={products} striped hover>
      </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
  )
}
```

when I run the application I saw this error :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

the issue is because I did not include

```
<TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Once I put this line in then the application works fine.